# If $\{x_p\}$ converges to $x$, then $\{x\}\cup \{x_p\}$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

If $\{x_p\}$ converges to $x$, then $\{x\} \cup \{x_p\}$ is compact.

My attempt: If $x_p$ converges to $x$, then any subsequence will also converge to $x$. Then the set $\{x\} \cup \{x_p\}$ has every subsequence converging $x$, showing the set is sequentially compact. My book gives a different proof, but this is something I wanted to verify.

Comment: One can use the definition of compactness, and convergence, directly.

Comment: This is not quite right; the set $\{x\} \cup \{x_p\}$ contains sequences that are not subsequences of $\{x_p\}$.  For example, say our set is $\mathbb{R}$, $x_p = 1/p$, and $x=0$.  Then $\{x\} \cup \{x_p\}$ contains the sequence $1/2, 1/3, 1/2, 1/3, \dots$, which has no subsequence converging to 0.

Comment: @NateEldredge However, converge subsequence of $1/2,1/3,1/2,1/3,\cdots$ is converges to the element in $\{1/n:n\in \Bbb N\}\cup\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence {x$_p$} may have every subsequence converging to x but note that {x}$\cup${x$_p$} is **not** a sequence; it is a set. So considering a subsequence of something that is not a sequence doesn't make sense.

Also, sequentially compact is equivalent to compactness for metrizable spaces.  You could have some weird topological space where this is not the case.